# unable to use sign_out in ruby on rails devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In my small rails app I have a controller called say and two pages hello and goodbye in it. I installed devise in the app. Initially i was able to access the sing_in page as /users/sign_in and similarly for sign up. I was not able to sign out and due to not able to sign out i am not able to access sign up or sign in page again. Now I entered the following code int eh say/hello page

```
<h1>Say#hello</h1>
<% if user_signed_in? %>
Hey signed in as <%= current_user.email %>.Not you? 
<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path %>
<% else %>
Hey <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %> or Hey <%= link_to "Logup", new_user_registration_path %>
<% end %>
</p>
```

This the routes page of the app.

```
Demo::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
get "say/hello"
get "say/goodbye"
# The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

# You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
root :to => "say#hello"
end
```

Whenever I access the say/hello page, this is the output i get

```
  Links

Hey signed in as x@gmail.com.Not you? Logout
```

When I click logout. It says

```
No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
```

When I directly access users/sign_in I get routed to the say/hello page.

What mistake am I doing? How should I sign_out?

I have also tried

```
destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete
```

Comment: Try using devise_for :users, controllers: {
      sessions: 'sessions'} in stead of "devise_for :users" in your routes file. AND <%= link_to 'logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => "DELETE"%> in your html

Comment: Does it showing the same error? Do you have the sessions controller in your application?

Comment: Demo::Application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'sessions'}
  get "say/hello"
  get "say/goodbye"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root :to => "say#hello"

Comment: Ya bachan after changing the routes.rb and the html file I am getting the same error

Comment: Ok. Now if you don't have the sessions controller in your application. Just copy it from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb and place it in your controllers. And then change its first line as "class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController". Restart the server and try it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this could help

Try this in your routes.rb

devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end